# With ng-repeat skip over certain entries

Tags: angularjs

I have set up a `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div id="popular" ng-repeat="m in mods">
   <!-- stuff here -->
</div>

<div id="personal" ng-repeat="m in mods">
   <!-- stuff here -->    
</div>
```

My mods object looks like this:

```
var mods = [
   {id:1232, group:'popular', ....},
   {id:1231232, group:'personal', ...}
   {id:544, group:'personal', ...}
]
```

I want the ng-repeat in the first div to only create element if the `group=='popular'`, is this possible?

Comment: use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).  You should consider asking a more specific question than "is this possible", since this is a very easy thing to find in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Claies very much, im a bit new to angular I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like,

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
        <div id="popular" ng-repeat="m in mods | weDontLike: 'personal'">   
            {{m}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


angular.module('myApp', []).filter('weDontLike', function () {

    return function (items, name) {

        var arrayToReturn = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].group != name) {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});

function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.mods = [{
        id: 1232,
        group: 'popular'
    }, {
        id: 1231232,
        group: 'personal'
    }, {
        id: 544,
        group: 'personal'
    }]
}
```

### OR

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
        <div id="popular" ng-repeat="m in mods | filter: {group : 'personal'}">{{m}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/3vju44r4/)

Comment: Thanks so much @Tribute!

Comment: Is this the simplest way? I was trying to do something like `m in mods | filter:(m.group == 'personal')`